# MongoDB Atlas limitations - writes per second, reads per second

Tags: mongodb, performance

We are evaluating MongoDB Atlas for our use case (ML/AI data accessed on the UI).
I was checking the mongoDB documentation regarding wps(writes per second) & rps(reads per second) limits, but am unable to find any definite answer.

The objective is to ensure that if i have large number of writes(or reads), they don't fail because of MongoDB limitations.

Any pointers on the wps/rps limitations ?

Comment: They don't throttle read/writes on mongo level, the limits come from underlying cloud providers who set IOPS. As a rule of thumb, the higher tier the more IOPS you get. Unfortunately different providers use different base to calculate IOPS so they are not really comparable. E.g. M30 on AWS declares 3,000 AWS IOPS and M30 on Azure declares 120 Microsoft IOPS.  But even these numbers don't tell you much because of Mongo's in-memory working sets. You will need to test it with your data shape and read/write patterns.

Comment: @AlexBlex - thanks for the update, as you mentioned - it depends on the mage chosen in the specific cloud provider